# google sheets - Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have created a form using google forms, and I want to automatically check the answers when a new submit is done.
When the user submit his/her question, a new line is added in a responses sheet. This is where I need to add some magic ;)

SO, in my responses sheet, I have the right answers in the second line...something like this

```
      A               B             C
1

2 RightAnswer1, RightAnswer2, RightAnswer3....
```

Using the arrayformula function, I have added new colums (column D,E,F,G and so on) on every row checking against the correct answer on line 2.

The formula goes something like this;

```
=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(A3:A=A2),1,0)
```

And it works like a charm :)

BUT, then I want to add a column at the end of each row with the sum of all the right answers, lets say to column Z on every row...this is where I want to sum all the 1's (correct answers).

I have tried something like this;

```
=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(<any kind of check that is true>),sum(D3:Z3),0)
```

This will always return the sum of D3:Z3 on every line, and this is not what I want. I want to sum the columns on the line-number that was just added. So I have tried to alter this expression in several ways , having everything in the arrayformula expression, altering the sum expression to (D3:D) to hopefully get it to work on the current line, but without any luck.

I have search the web for answers, but found nothing to help me...
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One way:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(D3:D),SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(D3:Z3),ROW(D3:D)),ROW(D3:D),D3:Z),))`

Although it would be possible to "skip the middle man" and process the raw data alone; assuming the answers are in A2:Z2, and the data to sum is in A3:Z, then:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A3:A),COUNTIF(IF(A3:Z=A2:Z2,ROW(A3:A)),ROW(A3:A)),))`